# Nominalisierung von "abhärten sich" zu Person

Tags: noun, nominalization

Wie wird eine Person genannt, die Abhärtung praktiziert?

EDIT: Ich meine kaltes Wasser.

[image]

Comment: Kannst du etwas genauer ausführen, was genau du meinst? In welchem Zusammenhang taucht diese Frage auf? Was könnte deiner Meinung  nach die richtige Antwort sein? Und was genau macht dich bei deiner Vermutung so unsicher, dass du dir die Mühe machst, hier zwar eine Frage zu stellen, uns aber nichts über die Hintergründe zu verraten??

Comment: *der/die/das sich Abhärtende*

Comment: Praktiker(in) der Abhärtung?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia: Winterbaden](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winterbaden) one of the following matches the picture:

- Winterbadende(r)
- Eisbadende(r)
- Eisschwimmer(in), Winterschwimmer(in), if the person also tries to swim to get minimal warmth by moving muscles

Without the picture I would simply use *Kaltduscher*, even if the opposite. *Warmduscher*, is more widely used for persons avoiding any kind of *Abhärtung*.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such expression for an "Abhärter" although I can easily create this word. Since the term Kaltduscher/Warmduscher was invented some years ago, it's the only way to express that meaning. Another new development is the adoption of "Iron Man/Maid".